# Idea to solve $\frac{dy}{dx}+x*(x+y)=x^3*(x+y)^3$ ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I find this equation in this website

http://www.prise2tete.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?id=10003

$\frac{dy}{dx}+x*(x+y)=x^3*(x+y)^3$

But the author don't answer and i want to know if it is possible to solve it or not? because it's very very hard ...

Shadock (i'm same Shadock :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This belongs to an Abel equation of the first kind.

Since the terms has a common factor $x+y$ , letting $u=x+y$ can slightly simplify this ODE:

Then $y=u-x$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{du}{dx}-1$

$\therefore\dfrac{du}{dx}-1+xu=x^3u^3$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=x^3u^3-xu+1$

Please follow the method in http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2

Comment: Not easy to understand but thank you ! :)